# How to select options from select2 with the help of selenium IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, jquery-select2

I'm working with some test case scenarios where I have multiple select2 options inside my forms. I'm trying to fill in the select2 boxes with values coming from my server (AJAX request).
I tried using selenium recorder. Which is not a good help. It doesn't understand the working of select2.

I'm putting my commands below.

```
@driver.get(@base_url + "/app/customers")
@driver.find_element(:link, "Add Customer").click
@driver.find_element(:name, "customer[name]").click
@driver.find_element(:name, "customer[name]").clear
@driver.find_element(:name, "customer[name]").send_keys "Chinmay"
Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(@driver.find_element(:xpath, "//*[@id=\"page-content\"]/div/div/div/div/form/div[4]/div[1]/div[4]/select")).select_by(:text, "label=Primary")
```

And the last line is throwing following error

```
[error] Option with label 'Primary' not found
```

My HTML code is just as follows

```
<select class="form-control amura-select2 select2-hidden-accessible" data-type="ds" data-name="address_types" data-default="only" style="width:100%;" required="required" name="customer[address_attributes][address_type]" aria-required="true" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="primary">Primary</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. That's not a good idea to use selenium IDE for code creation
2. Please think about capybara or watir-webdriver. You will like it.
3. Try to do something like

   ```
   wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) #Let's wait until Ajax-request will be done
   wait.until { @driver.find_element(xpath: "//option[@value='primary']") } #That's the waiting
   dropdown = @driver.find_element(xpath: "//select[@data-name='address_types']") #Nice way to find your dropdown
   select_list = Selenium::WebDriver::Support::Select.new(dropdown) #Let's create select_list out of dropdown-element
   select_list.select_by(:text, 'Primary') #Finally.
   ```

Comment: I know the pros and cons of using selenium IDE. I also have the solution using Capybara. But I have another use case, for which I want to do this. So do you have anything helpful regarding this code?

Comment: To be clear: Selenium-webdriver code is provided above. Do you need selenium IDE version (on selenise)?

Comment: I found the different solution. Even your solution worked. Using runScript command, I ran few select2 scripts. And it's working like I wanted.